# How can I convert gesture location to ARKit scene space?

Tags: swift, arkit

I'm trying to drag an SCNNode into the current scene at the location of the drag.

```swift
var currentBlock: SCNNode?

@objc func handlePan (gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // Location of Pan
    var location = gesture.location(in: self.sceneView)
        
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        // Add Node Reference, add Node to Scene
        if redBlockUI?.frame.contains(location) == true {
            currentBlock = createBlock(color: .red, location: location)
        }
    case .changed:
        // Drag Node Here
        currentBlock?.position = SCNVector3(location.x, location.y, -1)
    case .ended:
        // Remove Node Reference (Don't delete from Scene)
        currentBlock = nil
    default: break
    }
}

func createBlock (color: UIColor, location: CGPoint) -> SCNNode {
    // Make Geometry
    let block: SCNGeometry = SCNBox(width: 10.0, height: 10.0, length: 10.0, chamferRadius: 1.0)
    block.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = color
    // Attach Geometry to SCNNode
    let blockNode = SCNNode(geometry: block)
    blockNode.position = SCNVector3(location.x, location.y, -1)
    // Add to scene
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(blockNode)
    return blockNode
}
```

The object is not created at this position, though. Is there some sort of point conversion I need to make? Thanks!

Comment: This is to be created infront of the camera, I'm not using a hit test because I don't want to place it on some plane.

Answer (score 0):

SceneKit includes 2 functions for this: projectPoint to convert a 3D location to 2D and unprojectPoint to perform the reverse conversion.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524089-projectpoint
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522631-unprojectpoint